# Correct Way to Write a Statement in First-Order Logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am teaching myself set theory. I am at a point where the set of rationals, $\mathbb{Q}$, has been defined, along with its ordering relation, $<_\mathbb{Q}$. Now, working towards a definition of a Dedekind left set, the following definition has been provided:

$\mathbf{r}\subset\mathbb{Q}$ is closed to the left if for all $q\in\mathbf{r}$, if $p<_\mathbb{Q} q$, then $p\in\mathbf{r}$.

What I would like to do is write the above statement formally using the language of first-order logic. I have come up with the following:

$\forall p \forall q ((q \in \mathbf{r} ) \wedge (p <_\mathbb{Q} q) \rightarrow p \in \mathbf{r})$

However, what bothers me in the above statement is that it holds for all $p$ and $q$,  but the ordering relation $<_\mathbb{Q}$ is not defined for all $p$ and $q$.

Is this OK? Is there a better way to write this statement?

Comment: I have asked a more specific question on the notation of the universal quantification here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685273/qualification-of-a-universal-quantification I think it articulates my confusion better, so I would be happy to delete this one if anyone thinks the two are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is fine.

It says that for all p and q, If both $q\in r$ AND $p\lt_\mathbb Q q$, then...

It says nothing about what follows when the relation $<_\mathbb Q$ is not defined for $p, q$: the consequent in the implication follows for all $p, q$ that meet the criteria of the antecedent.

Just a simple example. If we let the domain of discourse to be the set of animals, and let $B(x)$ denote "x is an bird", and $F(x)$ denote "x has feathers", then $$\forall x(B(x)\rightarrow F(x))$$ What we are asserting is true whenever "x" is a bird. What is true about non-birds isn't in question here.

If you'd be more comfortable, perhaps add a third conjunct: $q\in r \land p\in \mathbb Q \land p<_\mathbb Q q$. That way, the conclusion is true for every $p, q$ that make the antecedent true.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. But what about, for example, $q\in \mathbf{r}$ and $p \not\in \mathbb{Q}$? Does $p<_\mathbb{Q}q$ by definition become false in this case, such that the AND is violated? Also, am I right that it is not allowed to write $\forall (p\in\mathbb{Q})\forall(q\in\mathbf{r}) (...)$?

Comment: There's no need to. The conclusion follows *exactly when* both conjuncts are satisfied. $p \lt_\mathbb Q q$ can only be satisfied when $p \in \mathbb Q$. If either conjunct is not satisfied, then the conclusion may be false or it may be true. What we know is that whenever the antecedent is true, the consequent must be true.